# Is it possible to implement Conditional Select on exposed filters in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I wonder whether it would be possible to implement something similar to http://bit.ly/MEdfiq using views exposed filters? That is to only show the data that is relevant to a previously selected exposed filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) contrib module, It's an awesome module to achieve that.

Here's a documentation for [hierarchical select API](http://drupal.org/node/532724).

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, Does it integrate with views?

Comment: I believe it does. It has a sub module called Hierarchical Select Views. -Muhammad...

Comment: I am just wondering whether http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks/#views_filters_selective will provide this functionality since it will limit the views filters to those present in the result set. I think it is more appropriate. Do you have any experience with it?